# Can I create tabs inside a tab in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, maui

I'm creating a profile page and want to create 3 tabs inside the page. Previously when I used `Xamarin` I used `Xamarin Community Toolkit` that provided `TabView` which allowed me to create tabs inside other tabs. However, I'm transitioning to `.NET MAUI` and am having trouble with creating inner tabs. From the picture below I used `TabBar` in `Shell` to create the outer tabs which are the three icons at the bottom of the screen. Now I want to create 3 inner tabs inside the page but don't know how to approach this. I colored the area red where I want the 3 inner tabs to be located. so I want three `Tab` titles to be located on top of the red area and the rest shows the content of each tab. Should I utilize `TabbedPage` or `TabBar` to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: [Bottom and Top Tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs#bottom-and-top-tabs).

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you need a `TabView` component in your project. However, the `TabView` hasn't been implemented in [CommunityToolkit](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui) specifically for `Maui`. You can follow up the proposal link below:

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/121

As an alternative workaround suggested by Steve, you can try to use [Bottom and top tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs#bottom-and-top-tabs) in `Shell`.

When more than one `ShellContent` object is present in a `Tab` object, a top tab bar is added to the bottom tab, through which the `ContentPage` objects are navigable:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Domestic"
            Icon="paw.png">
         <ShellContent Title="Cats"
                         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
          <ShellContent Title="Dogs"
                         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Monkeys"
            Icon="monkey.png">
          <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
     </Tab>
</TabBar>
```